# not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1) in python

Tags: python

Code:

```
import re

abc=("Above them, her thick black brows slanted upward, cutting a " , "startling oblique line above her hows thick iwa her magnolia-white skin--that skin so" ,"rews ghij the Cutting ABove"
for line in abc:
       line_string = line.strip()
       processed_string = re.sub(r'[^a-zA-Z0-9\ ]', '', line_string).lower()
       word, count = processed_string.split('\t', 1)
```

I am getting the error below:

```
File "C:\\Users\\Simar\\untitled4.py", line 17, in \<module\>
word, count = processed_string.split('\\t', 1)

ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)
```

How can this be fixed?

Comment: There are no tabs in your strings. So the `split` returns a list of one element...

Comment: The code in the error message doesn't match the code in your question...

Answer (score 0):

So, you're getting this error because the last line of your code is trying to split strings based on tab characters, but there aren't any tab characters in your input.

If you print the value generated by the last line of the loop, rather than assigning it, you see that the right-hand side of the assignment contains a single string, whereas the `word, count =`  code expects a tuple that will unpack to two values.

```py
import re

abc=("Above them, her thick black brows slanted upward, cutting a " , "startling oblique line above her hows thick iwa her magnolia-white skin--that skin so" ,"rews ghij the Cutting ABove"


for line in abc:
       line_string = line.strip()
       processed_string = re.sub(r'[^a-zA-Z0-9\ ]', '', line_string).lower()
       print(processed_string.split('\t', 1))
```

This gives, as output:

```
['above them her thick black brows slanted upward cutting a']
['startling oblique line above her hows thick iwa her magnoliawhite skinthat skin so']
['rews ghij the cutting above']
```

It's unclear where you want the value of `count` to come from, so I can't suggest a fix for that without a bit more information.

Answer (score -1):

The lines you are trying to process do not have the character `\t`.

Therefore, even if you put the `maxsplit` to 1, you will have only one value (not two) because splitting doesn't have any effect.

Comment: The `split` does have an effect!

Comment: Yes, it is returning a list instead of a string. I meant without effects in the sense that the string is not separated.